# Jenkins job is failing due to manager credentials not showing on Jenkins screen(post-build action)

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, war

Build Job for war file on Jenkins in failing, it giving error message:

FailedConsole Output
Started by upstream project "package" build number 4
originally caused by:
 Started by user harish nair
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/deploy-to-staging
Unable to access upstream artifacts area /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/package/builds/4/archive. Does source project archive artifacts?
ERROR: Failed to copy artifacts from package with filter: **/*.war
Finished: FAILURE

[image]

I am trying to build deploy-to-staging with a build from package job, package job has build successfully but deploy-to-staging is not getting built
[image]

Above image i have given properly in build section, but in post-build action section irrespective of adding all the details i am not getting manager user name and manager password.

I have already added manager credentials in conf/tomcat-users.xml also:
[image]

Please help with resolving this issue how to get a successful build for my Jenkins job on tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved by adding manager user name and pwd after clicking on Jenkins icon in post-build action and by clicking on add.

In the copy artifacts to another project plugin we have to also change which build : 'Copy from WORKSPACE from latest completed build'

This will resolve this issue.